# Draft.js Custom Button for Custom Block

Tags: draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I am trying to wrap my head around [custom block components](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-block-components.html#content) in draft.js and I am following this [tutorial](http://bitwiser.in/2016/08/31/implementing-todo-list-in-draft-js.html).

The tutorial mentions a way to detect the input and go into a custom block mode, in this case on inputting `[]` when a block is empty, we go into todo mode and render TodoBlock.

Now, since we are using `handleBeforeInput` to detect if we need to enter the todo mode, we get the live `editorState` as a callback and are able to [avoid race conditions](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-editorstate-race-conditions.html#content).

I want to achieve a custom block state with the press of an external button, in this case, divider mode to render DividerBlock but in a custom button, I only have the local component `editorState` to work with.

I am running into the [race condition](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-editorstate-race-conditions.html#content) and I am not able to enter the custom block mode.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6xy68r3rjz) of my exploration so far.

So, in summary, there are two custom blocks:-

- TodoBlock - enter todo block mode via handleBeforeInput i.e. getting live editor state the callback and this works.
- DividerBlock - enter divider block mode via external button i.e. getting editor state via local component which might be stale and this is not working